# Registering Pokémon weaknesses

Tags: swift, pokemon

I recently answered a question that had me wondering if I could simplify this below code **without** creating an extra function:

```
for object in objects {
    if let type = object["type"] where !type.isEmpty, let name = object["name"] {

        print(pokemonTypeDefenseChart[type])
        for weakness in pokemonTypeDefenseChart[type]! {
            if pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] == nil {
                pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] = []
            }
            pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness]?.append(name)
        }
    }

    if let typeTwo = object["typeTwo"] where !typeTwo.isEmpty, let name = object["name"] {
        for weakness in pokemonTypeDefenseChart[typeTwo]! {
            if pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] == nil {
                pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] = []
            }
            pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness]?.append(name)
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially the code loops through objects (list of pokemon) and is designed to add all of the pokemon weak to type (and optionally typeTwo).

I ended up just refactoring the `for` statements inside the `if let` statements into a function, but I was wondering if it was possible to compress these without an extra function. The only difference is the type.

I know I could simplify it a bit by using a map instead of `for` loops but I wanted to keep it more understandable for the question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
for x in ["type", "typeTwo"] {
    if let type = object[x] where !type.isEmpty,
        let name = object["name"],
        defenseChart = pokemonTypeDefenseChart[type] { /* ... */ }
}
```

Also, to simplify the rest of your code, you could extend `Dictionary` like this:

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(key: Key, fallback fallback: Value) -> Value {
        get { return self[key] ?? fallback }
        set { self[key] = newValue }
    }
}
```

This allows you to replace this:

```
for weakness in defenseChart {
    if pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] == nil {
        pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] = []
    }
    pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness]?.append(name)
}
```

by this:

```
for weakness in defenseChart {
    pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness, fallback: []].append(name)
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you provide a `set` for the `Dictionary.subscript(_:fallback:)`? It seems like that that interface is not contributing anything.

Comment: @CAD97 By providing both a getter and a setter, we can apply mutating functions to that subscript (in this case `append`).

Comment: @TimVermeulen ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now,  but something like this might work,  I am assuming each type in pokemonTypeDefenseChart is an array,  so I combine the arrays , then loop through it once.  Normally I would filter out dups, but you can't add functions, so I check if the name does not exist, and append if it doesn't

```
for object in objects {
    if let name = object["name"] {
        let defense = (
            (object["type"].flatMap({pokemonTypeDefenseChart[$0]}) ?? []) + 
            (object["typeTwo"].flatMap {pokemonTypeDefenseChart[$0]} ?? []))

        for weakness in defense {
            if pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] == nil {
                pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] = []
            }
            if (pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness]?.contains(name)) == nil {
                pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness]?.append(name)
            }
            print(pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] )
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks to @TimVermeulen for cleaning up some parts of the answer

Comment: I am assuming that if I call defense chart on isEmpty, that I am getting a nil result

Comment: `type ?? ""` doesn't make sense, because `type` is non-optional at that point. Same applies to `typeTwo`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen why wouldnt it be optional,  we do not know if object["type"] exists

Comment: @TimVermeulen I added a space to help distinguish the brace (This is why I like the brace on the next line lol)

Comment: Oh! The double space between `if` and `let` might have added to the confusion, because it aligns the `let` statements. Either way, why not add `type` and `typeTwo` to the `if let`?

Comment: @TimVermeulen Because you could have type nil OR typeTwo nil,  then my if would fail,  didnt notice that double space,  fixed that, thanks

Comment: You never know if the OP wants to include MissingNo into his pokedex  (I think I had a MissingNo once that only had type2 filled in)

Comment: Good point! Still, this assumes that `pokemonTypeDefenseChart` has no `""` key. What about `type.flatMap { pokemonTypeDefenseChart[$0] }`?

Comment: Wouldnt that merge all the types. not just the 2 he is checking,  wait type, is a String,  could you do flatMap on strings?  I am still new to these  type of functions

Comment: No, you should look up how `flatMap` for optionals work. This statement results in the dictionary lookup if the key is non-`nil`, and `nil` otherwise.

Comment: @TimVermeulen, you commented before I edited,  I am assuming type is a string, but it may be an enum,  but either way I do not think flatMap works on them

Comment: `type` is an optional, right? Then `flatMap` works on it. See here: http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Optional/#func-flatmap_

Comment: @TimVermeulen, ok I see where you are going with this,  yes it would work,  then I do not have to worry about guessing what his instanceType is

Comment: @TimVermeulen That documentation is confusing, how is map and flatmap any different in that regard

Comment: `flatMap` takes a closure that returns an optional, and unwraps it in case it isn't `nil`. If you use a closure that returns an optional in `map`, you'll end up with double optionals (in Swift 3 at least).